# What does `exposed-modules` do in `elm-package.json`?

Tags: elm

What is `exposed-modules` property in `elm-package.json` for?

Or better yet, if anyone has link to the documentation for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is used for writing Elm packages that are meant for distribution.

> `exposed-modules` lets you expose some small set of modules. Use this to stop internal details from polluting your API and cluttering the docs with modules that are not meant for users.

[Source](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-package/blob/master/README.md)